# Cannot find module(s) NodeJs with Electron after building

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I have a electron app that works with `npm start electron .` on my Mac. However when I built it using electron-packager to compile it for the Mac, I get the following errors upon opening the compiled Application file

```
bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
module.js:487 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)...
module.js:487 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'node-wifi'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
```

I believe it has to do with setting the right file paths, but I have tried the following in my index.js and functions.js file and it has not worked:

```
var path = require('path');

module.paths.push(path.resolve('node_modules'));
module.paths.push(path.resolve('../node_modules'));
```

These are other relevant files and commands below:

package.json:

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.8.4",
    "electron-packager": "^12.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^12.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "electron-reload": "^1.2.2",
    "electron-store": "^1.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-wifi": "^2.0.4",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.18.0"
  }
```

Build Command:

```
electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64  --prune=true --out=release-builds
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Hello World!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
      <script src="functions.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
      // On click we should send event to close window.
    </script>
    </head>
```

index.js (dependencies)

```
const {app, BrowserWindow , ipcMain, dialog} = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
```

functions.js (dependencies)

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
var child_process = require('child_process');
var wifi = require('node-wifi');
var swal = require('sweetalert2');
const Store = require('electron-store');
const store = new Store();
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't like the `--prune=true` in the build command. I set that to false and it seems to be working.